# Modulate from A minor to D major

Tags: modulation

Can you recommend a smooth way to modulate from A minor to D major? I know a way to modulate down a fifth between major/major, but cannot really apply it here.

My ideas would be modulating to C major first and then to D major, or dominanticize a minor. Do you have practical examples?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's "smooth" enough, but personally I'd just turn Am into AM and you've got your dominant! (Or maybe that's what you meant by "dominanticize.")

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate, but in addition there are two problems here: 1) the question just calls for a list of answers of equal value, and 2) it's borderline opinion-based.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the context?  If you edit the question to frame it in terms of prior harmonies and the musical idiom, it might be made less opinion-based.

Comment: Hi @AndyBonner, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Max Reger ("Supplement to Modulation") suggests a-d-Eb/G-A-D or i-iv=i-N63-V-I.

I had thought of a-d/F-F7-Bb7b5-D/A-A(7)-D; or extended a-d7-G7-F7-Bb7b5-D/A-A7-D.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of ways of doing this. You could for example simply go

`am - F - G - A(7) - D`

which shortly modulates to C major, but resolves in an altered deceptive cadence, which gives us the dominant for D.

You could do something like

`am - B7 - E7 - A7 - D`

Or

`am - f#ø - B - em - A7 - D`

If you want you can do some altered mediants like

`am - dm - F - Bb - Gb - D`

Answer (score 0):

Many ways! Simple straightforward, just go Dm>D.

Or use the dominant of both to get from Dm>D.

Or tts:E♭7>D.

Too many to mention, really.